# How could I make tagged user in the comment a hyperlink to that user's home page? (Django)

Tags: python, html, django, web, hyperlink

Just like the facebook, if I tag someone in my comment, like "@Mike" and then after I post that, then in the website, I could see my comment there and the content of the comment has the @Mike which is a hyperlink that I click it, it could redirect me to that user's page. I have no idea how I should do that, any suggestions?

By the way currently I could retrieve the tagged user's name to my backend, I just don't know how to render that user's name back as a hyperlink.

Comment: Capture some user-unique field (ID? Username?) in a URL and render that user's information on some "User Page" template? Then it's just a matter of pointing the link in the right place.

Comment: URL dispatching pretty much covers how urls are handled either as "static" (always pointing to the same content) or as "dynamic" (using arguments).
Create the necessary view, create the url that points to that view using a username (or something else) as the user identifier and you should be just fine.

Comment: After I tagged some user, I render that to the template <P>{{ comment }}<P>, so the page source is like <P> @Mike is a fool<P>, I mean how could I make this "@Mike" hyperlink, just this "@Mike", not the whole <P> tag content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `template tag`: **safe**.

Let's say that your post context variable is: `quote` = `@Mike is a fool`

Grab `@Mike`, and add the `html` to make it a link and reinsert it when saving the post.  So the saved post is:

`quote` = `<a href="mikes_homepage">@Mike</a> is a fool`

And then use **safe** in your `html template`:

```
{{ quote|safe }}
```

Here is the documentation link for `safe` template tags:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Comment: Cool, the safe template tag is all the thing I needed here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook asks from the browser to their database at each keypress after `@`. As soon as you select the user name, lets say `@Mike` they add an input field to the form with the value you selected, something like:

```
<input value="@12345678:Mike"></input>.
```

You submit the comment, and the server processes your request, substituting `@Mike` in your textbox with whatever they want using the `<input>` value.

Answer (score 0):

this should work
after you save your form put this script

`p = re.compile('@[a-z]+')
        for word in yourform.comment.split():
            if p.match(word) != None:
                new_word=list(word)[1:len(list(word))]
                name=''
                for elenemts in new_word:
                    name += elements`

write below line in 'if' condition(not able to write here with proper indentation)

```
new_comment=re.sub('@[a-z]+','<a href='+name+'s_profile>'+name+'</a>',yourform.comment)`
```

now in your template render your "new_comment" as safe

`{{ new_comment|safe }}`